# Duplicate Rule Issue when differentiating Record Types

Tags: duplicate-management, matcher

We have a Custom Object 'Target' In our application.It has total 5 record types and each record type has respective duplicate rule.
The purpose of the the custom object is to set the target for particular Financial Year.Meaning we create only 12 records for each record type.

For this We have 3 fields which are used in all record types.

```
1.Financial Year
2.Financial Quarter
3.Target Type(Value=Monthly)
```

above 3 fields are using in all record types & Matching Criteria of Duplicate Rule.we have 4 record types whose matching rule includes above 3 fields and 1 additional field which is different based on record type.

There is only one record type 'Science & Tech' whose matching rule contain above 3 field only.

Now problem is when I try to create Science&Tech Record(No Duplicate Record),it throws duplicate error message and shows duplicate record of another record types.I checked the debug log and I've found that it executes duplicate rule for Science &Tech but at the same time it also executes duplicate Rule for other record types.

If I create Science&Tech Record then it allows me to create a record and if the Science&Tech Record is already exists then it should throw the error message.

I am not sure why it is showing other record type records.

Can Someone please suggest how can I avoid this situation?

**P.S. I have added Record Type Filter for each Duplicate Rule.**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can add RecordType in the Matching Rule Criteria based on this feature request in Ideas:

> ## [Include Record Type as a field option for Matching Rules.](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjXBAA0)
>
> When setting up Matching Rules, there are times when you may want to allow duplicates values in a field if the record types don’t also match. To do this it would be helpful if we could also include the Record Type in the Matching Rule.

Comment: But I can add Record Type filter in Duplicate Rule.